# Proving free group $F_2$ is not isomorphic to $F_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I'm trying to prove the free group on 3 generators is not isomorphic to the free group on 2 generators. I have that there are many injections $F_3 \hookrightarrow F_2$ and of course $F_2 \hookrightarrow F_3$, which implies there is a bijection between the two, and I suppose the bijection is not going to be homomorphic and hence not an isomorphism. But I'm not sure how to prove this: I can explicitly show various injective homomorphisms $F_3 \hookrightarrow F_2$ but how do you prove that *all* such maps between the two free groups are not isomorphisms?

I've seen the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35229/free-groups-f-x-cong-f-y-rightarrowx-y), a rather long discussion that isomorphism implies equal cardinality. This question is the converse which is not true: equal cardinality does not imply isomorphism.

Comment: Consider their (respective) abelianizations.

Comment: We have $|X|=2\neq 3=|Y|$.

Comment: Actually both groups are infinite, they differ in the number of generators. But by showing injections both ways the cardinality of both groups is equal by Schroeder Bernstein.

Comment: @lulu is there a simpler approach? This was a bonus problem in week 1 of an old course and all we had at this point was basic group theory (Artin ch. 2) and the definition of a free group.

Comment: BBrooklyn, the answer by "bof" at the duplicate is very elementary:"Let $G$ be some group of order $n$ where $1\lt n\lt\aleph_0$. If $F_X\cong F_Y$, then the number of homomorphisms from $F_X$ to $G$ is equal to the number of homomorphisms from $F_Y$ to $G$, that is, $n^{|X|}=n^{|Y|}$. If $\min(|X|,|Y|)$ is finite, it follows from $n^{|X|}=n^{|Y|}$ that $|X|=|Y|$. If $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are both infinite, then $|X|=|F_X|=|F_Y|=|Y|$."

Comment: What lulu suggested is [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579729/the-quotient-of-a-free-group-of-rank-n-and-its-commutator-subgroup-is-isomor). We have $(F_2)_{ab}\cong \Bbb Z^2$ and $(F_3)_{ab}\cong \Bbb Z^3$, so they are not isomorphic. This is not much simpler than the above argument, I think.

Comment: You are confusing what "equal cardinality" means in the post you link to. It's the cardinality of a *free generating set*, not of the groups itself. Equal cardinality of free generating set *definitely* implies isomorphism.